# Why was Dumbledore worried by the cut in Harry's arm?

Tags: harry-potter

In the *Goblet of Fire*, Harry is cut in the arm by Pettigrew.
When Dumbledore learns it, he's extremely worried and wants to check Harry's arm.

Why?

> When Harry told of Wormtail piercing his arm with the dagger, however, Sirius let out a vehement exclamation and Dumbledore stood up so quickly that Harry
>   started. Dumbledore walked around the desk and told Harry to stretch out his arm.
>   Harry showed them both the place where his robes were torn and the cut beneath
>   them.
>
> "He said my blood would make him stronger than if he'd used someone else's,"
>   Harry told Dumbledore. "He said the protection my - my mother left in me - he'd
>   have it too. And he was right - he could touch me without hurting himself, he
>   touched my face."
>
> For a fleeting instant, Harry thought he saw a gleam of something like triumph in
>   Dumbledore's eyes. But next second. Harry was sure he had imagined it, for when
>   Dumbledore had returned to his seat behind the desk, he looked as old and weary
>   as Harry had ever seen him.
>
> "Very well," he said, sitting down again. "Voldemort has overcome that particular
>   barrier. Harry, continue, please.

---

Edit:

Plz explain this sentence specifically:

> "Dumbledore walked around the desk and told Harry to stretch out his
>   arm."

Comment: Is [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26891/whats-the-significance-of-this-passage-from-the-goblet-of-fire) your question?

Comment: No. I thought there was something significant about the cut itself, but it seems I'm wrong.

Answer (score 23):

Because this propagated Harry's blood - and with it, his protection from Voldemort - into V's blood.

Dumbledore confirmed it in HP7, Ch 35, "King's Cross":

> “He took your blood believing it would strengthen him. **He took into his body a tiny part of the enchantment your mother laid upon you when she died for you. His body keeps her sacrifice alive, and while that enchantment survives, so do you** and so does Voldemort’s one last hope for himself.”
>   Dumbledore smiled at Harry, and Harry stared at him.

...

> “Without meaning to, as you now know, Lord Voldemort doubled
>   the bond between you when he returned to a human form.
>   A part of his soul was still attached to yours, and, thinking to
>   strengthen himself, he took a part of your mother’s sacrifice into
>   himself. **If he could only have understood the precise and terrible
>   power of that sacrifice, he would not, perhaps, had dared to touch
>   your blood.** . . . But then, if he had been able to understand, he
>   could not be Lord Voldemort, and might never have murdered at
>   all.

Comment: Then why do they want to look at Harry's arm?

Comment: @ALS - they didn't "want to look" - they saw what he told and showed. See the quote I added to the Q.

Comment: "Dumbledore walked around the desk and told Harry to stretch out his arm."

Comment: This doesn’t seem to really answer the question asked here. It seems instead like an answer to the linked question of why Dumbledore had a gleam of triumph.

Answer (score 4):

Dumbledore is a man who is always for absolute facts.Probably,by taking a look at Harry's cut arm,he wanted to make sure if his blood had indeed been used to rejuvenate Lord Voldemort.By this, probably he wanted to confirm his theory about the doubled bond between Lord Voldemort and Harry..

As Dumbledore addresses Harry:

> “Without meaning to, as you now know, Lord Voldemort doubled the bond
>   between you when he returned to a human form. A part of his soul was
>   still attached to yours, and, thinking to strengthen himself, he took
>   a part of your mother’s sacrifice into himself. If he could only have
>   understood the precise and terrible power of that sacrifice, he would
>   not, perhaps, had dared to touch your blood.."

Answer (score 2):

Is this not the story behind why Harry must "die" to bring down V? The cut was to get access to Harry's blood and make himself immune to the magic that killed him the first time, but by doing so, he showed his weakness and Dumbledore knew what that entailed. The glimmer of triumph was Dumbledore realizing they now had a way to defeat him, then the loss of it was realizing Harry must "die" to fulfill it. The only reason he wanted to see the cut was to make sure blood was drawn and enough had been collected to perform the spell. If the cut had been shallow and not drawn blood or barely scratched him, then they would have to think of a new way to fight.

Comment: Harry was accidentally made into a Horcrux the night Voldemort murdered James and Lilly.  That is why Harry had to die.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, he wasn't that worried.
There is a line in Goblet of fire. "Harry would have sworn that he seen a glimpse of triumph on Dumbledore's face, but then he thought he was imagining"